How to get last modified time of a folder in Dropbox using java api?
I know there is a method available for getting last modified date of a File (filemetadata.getClientModified).
But, there is no method for getting last modified date for a Folder in FolderMetadata.
How can I get this value for Folder?
One way is to track last modified time of Files in the Folder and assign the latest value to Folder. But what if it is a empty folder?
Please suggest.
I am using java 17.0 and dropbox java sdk version7.0.0

For Non-empty folder, You can use listfolder() function and get the latest client_modified date from the folder.You will be able to see a timestamp and check the latest client_modified consider as the last modified date.
For empty folders, you have to do it manually because there is no file to track but still you can use metadata cache approach as well.

There is a Dropbox Forum thread you might have seen called "How to get last modified date for folders in Dropbox V2 API" (which is the API version you're using with the Java SDK 7.0).To shortly summarize

Over the years 2016 to 2019 a few people requested this feature, but it has not been implemented and Dropbox staff has had no news on it in its last reply in May 2019.

The Dropbox API documentation indicates this to be the same situation still: if you visit the files/get_metadata endpoint (which "returns the metadata for a file or folder"), scroll to the bottom of it and expand the details of FileMetadata and FolderMetadata, you'll see that

FileMetadata contains the properties client_modified and server_modified
FolderMetadata does not contain similar properties

So you're probably best off to follow the recommendation given by the Dropbox staff in the mentioned thread:

The only workaround would be to use list_folder to list all of the contents of the folder and monitor for changes to them, recording the latest time as the modified time for the folder.

Regarding the empty folder, you'll probably have no choice but to either always create a dummy file along a folder or to save the timestamp of its creation yourself somewhere.
